# Directory Sync with a Subdirectory to Ignore

Tags: macos, bash, shell, command-line, synchronization

I need to do a directory sync e.g. from `/dir-a/` to `/dir-b/` (always in this direction). However, there are two requirements:

1. There is a particular subdirectory `/dir-a/.dont-copy/` (yes, started with a `.`) that I should ignore. That is, `/dir-a/.dont-copy/` should always stay in `/dir-a/`, never move.
2. Files / directories in `/dir-b/` that don't exist in `/dir-a/` should be deleted.

How would I do this using **command-line tools** (ideally, on Mac OSX)? Thanks beforehand for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
$ rsync -avz --exclude=.dont-copy --delete dir-a/ dir-b
```

Note the trailing slash on dir-a.  If you omit that, you will get dir-b/dir-a.